# Unable to produce graph in Jmeter using Jmeter maven plugin,

Tags: java, maven, jmeter

The graph isn't getting generated after executing the command- mvn jmeter-graph:create-graph

I am getting the following error

Failed to execute goal de.codecentric:jmeter-graph-maven-plugin:0.1.0:create-graph (default-cli) on project testproject: Execution default-cli of goal de.codecentric:jmeter-graph-maven-plugin:0.1.0:create-graph failed: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to execute mojo.

Here is the pom.xml file of the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example1</groupId>
    <artifactId>testproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>testproject</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>
                    <propertiesUser>
                        <threadgroup.count>1</threadgroup.count>
                        <threadgroup.rampup>1</threadgroup.rampup>
                        <threadgroup.duration>1</threadgroup.duration>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format>csv</jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.label>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.label>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.latency>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.latency>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.successful>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.successful>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.time>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.time>
                    </propertiesUser>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>pre-site</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <mkdir dir="${basedir}/target/jmeter/results/dashboard" />
                                <copy file="${basedir}/src/test/resources/reportgenerator.properties"
                                      tofile="${basedir}/target/jmeter/bin/reportgenerator.properties" />
                                <copy todir="${basedir}/target/jmeter/bin/report-template">
                                    <fileset dir="${basedir}/src/test/resources/report-template" />
                                </copy>
                                <java>
                                    <arg value="-g" />
                                    <arg value="${basedir}/target/jmeter/results/*.jtl" />
                                    <arg value="-o" />
                                    <arg value="${basedir}/target/jmeter/results/dashboard/" />
                                </java>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-graph-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-graph-threads</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create-graph</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <inputFile>${basedir}/target/jmeter/results/*.jtl</inputFile>
                    <graphs>
                        <graph>
                            <pluginType>ResponseTimesOverTime</pluginType>
                            <width>800</width>
                            <height>600</height>
                            <outputFile>${basedir}/target/jmeter/results/dashboard-ResponseTimesOverTime.png</outputFile>
                        </graph>
                    </graphs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```